# Mustache JS not replacing tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, mustache

I'm trying to render an external template using Mustache. Like so (just simple example template):

```
<script id="donation-template" type="text/template">
<h1>{{value}} HELLO {{from}}</h1>{{url}}
</script>
```

And

```
// Print donation, using mustache
        printDonation = function (x,v) {
            // Template from local file.
            var template = $('#donation-template').html();
            // Render 
            var formattedHtml = Mustache.to_html(template, v);
            console.log(v);
            return formattedHtml;
        };
```

But Mustache seems to be ignoring its {{tags}}. As it only returns `<h1>HELLO</h1>`

I'm sure the objects is fine, as it works fine when I load the template internally. Object is

```
Object {url: "http://localhost:8080/b/?id=1", from: "daan", id: 1, value: 5}
```

Comment: What seems to be the problem? Works in the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ACbcj/)

Comment: I fixed it (but can't answer my own question). I'm using Django which killed the template tags before Mustache could use them.

in Mustache.js I could change the tags from {{}} to [[]]. Search for Mustache.tags in the mustache.js